# Does Column space = range = image of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does computing the column space, range, and image of a matrix all produce the same answer?  And are they all written the same way? for example.

Basis of the column space = {v1,v2}
Basis of the image =  {v1,v2}
Basis of the range = {v1,v2}

Comment: The exact term would be the image of the linear map associated to the matrix. By itself, a matrix has no  image.

Answer (score 4):

Yes: all of these terms refer to the same thing.